# Nachdem 1961 die Berliner Mauer gebaut wurde, glaubte kaum einer mehr an die Wiedervereinigung

Tags: sentence-structure

I read this sentence in *Menschen* but unfortunately I do not understand the construct of it! Where is the subject of the "Hauptsatz"?

Comment: Is Menschen a publication title?

Comment: yes, a book series to teach German as a foreign language.

Answer (score 4):

The subject is "kaum einer".

The sentence could be rewritten as:

> Kaum einer glaubte mehr an die Wiedervereinigung, nachdem 1961 die Berliner Mauer gebaut wurde

Comment: Isn't the subject just "einer"?

Comment: @Rompey You might be right, but I think either possibility comes close enough to answering the question